How can i achive more precison with thread::sleep_for?
I have an opengl program on windows 10 that uses separate threads to calculate/change position of dots on screen over time. Each thread calculates positon of its 1 dot in a loop (multiple dots on screen). Some dots change position faster than other via shorter delays on these threads between calculation of each new position. Seprate rendering threads taht takes changes into accoutn when updating screen. I tried to make the delay as little as approx 10 or more microseconds. However sleep_for makes massive difference for 1000us and 999us.
Why is such a difference between both threads sleep time ? Code example below.
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void example_func(int time){
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::microseconds(time));
    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - start);
    cout << "Intended time: "<<time<<", actual time: " << duration.count() << " microseconds" << std::endl;
}


int main() {
    thread thread1000(example_func, 1000); // gives more than 10000 us 
    thread thread999(example_func, 999); // gives 1 us 
    thread1000.join();
    thread999.join();
    return 0;
}

I also thought of the following alternative which seems to work correctly but, is it fine performance wise for above use case ?
void example_func_v2(int time) {
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto end = start + chrono::microseconds(time);

    auto start2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::this_thread::sleep_until(end);
    auto end2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration2 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end2 - start2);
    cout << "Intended time: "<<time<<", actual time: " << duration2.count() << " microseconds" << endl;
}


I tried to make the delay as little as approx 10 or more microseconds Your OS may not have that resolution.

General desktop hardware and OSes won't give you a resolution of much better than milliseconds. In general, a sleep gives you a delay of at least what you asked for, effectively rounding up to the next timer tick. But!!! Sometimes the number you give is too small, effectively rounds to zero, and turns into a yield, surrendering the CPU and then resuming as soon as it can be rescheduled.

In other words, you probably cannot get the timing you want out of sleep_for and will have to use something target-specific, if the target has a sub-microsecond clock. Either way, we need to know your target system to be able to answer the question conclusively. Please edit the question and add it.

Side note: Avoid using high_resolution_clock for timing. It's specified to allow clocks that favour resolution over stability and you could even have a clock that can jump backward in time. Advice from one of the creators of high_resolution_clock.

sleep_for sleeps for at least the time specified in its argument. And when the thread becomes active after the sleep there is no guarantee that the OS will immediately start running it. So when your thread resumes execution, check how long it was since the last time it ran and use that number to figure out its new position.

What platform are you running this on?

I run this on Windows 10

A real-time OS (a.k.a., "RTOS") will give you guaranteed latency, but I can't tell you whether there is any particular RTOS that can give the specific guarantees that you need for your application.

And since Windows is NOT a real time OS you cannot use it (reliably) for real time control

Re, "Each thread calculates positon of its 1 dot in a loop." That usually is an awful way to do animation. Usually what you want is one thread and one loop that animates all of the  "dots." Since the dots don't all move on the same schedule, you'll want to use a priority queue to keep track of future wake-up times so that the loop can know how long to sleep until the next one is due. (Basically, replicating in your own code, how the OS scheduler would have scheduled all of those different threads.)

high precision Sleep for values around 5 ms may give some additional insight, specifically using timeBeginPeriod to adjust the minimum timer resolution on Windows.

The timestep is always going to vary (feature of all non-realtime OS's) - please read Fix Your Timestep! for smooth animations.

Fwiw, here is a chrono implementation of the final solution in Fix Your Timestep!
